# Summarize many variables with a function of two variables

Tags: r, dplyr

The `summarise_if` function is very helpful to summary several variables. Assume that I need the mean of every numeric variable in my dataset. I can use

```
df <- as_tibble(iris)
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, .fun = mean)
```

This works perfectly. But assume now that the function in `.fun` involves 2 arguments from the dataset (an example is the `weighet.mean`, where the weight variable is Sepal.Length). I tried,

```
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, .fun = function(x, w) weighted.mean(x, w), w = Sepal.Length)
```

The error was

> Error in list2(...) : object 'Sepal.Width' not found

I suspect that R did not search `Sepal.Length` in `df` but in it global environment. So I have to use,

```
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, .fun = function(x, w) weighted.mean(x, w), w = df$Sepal.Length)
```

This works but it is not a good to do df$Sepal.Length. For example, it becomes completely impossible for me to compute the weighted mean by group.

```
df %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, .fun = function(x, w) weighted.mean(x, w), w = df$Sepal.Length)
```

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `Sepal.Length`.
> ℹ `Sepal.Length = (function (x, w) ...`.
> x 'x' and 'w' must have the same length
> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Species = setosa.

So, how to use `summarise_if` or `summarise_at` with functions involving two variables from the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to use `Sepal.Length` as `w`, concatenate (`c`) the output from `where(is.numeric)` and specify `-Sepal.Length` to remove the column from `across`, then use `weighted.mean` on the other numeric columns, with `w` as 'Sepal.Length'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -Sepal.Length), 
        ~ weighted.mean(., w = Sepal.Length)))
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
        <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1        3.05         3.97        1.29
```

---

Or a grouped one would be

```
df %>%
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -Sepal.Length), 
        ~ weighted.mean(., w = Sepal.Length)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Species    Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
  <fct>            <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa            3.45         1.47       0.248
2 versicolor        2.78         4.29       1.34 
3 virginica         2.99         5.60       2.03
```

NOTE: `_if`, `_at`, `_all` suffix functions are deprecated in favor for `across`

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know and I'm still using them. Just a question, why - in front of sepal.lenght

Comment: @Ari.stat just to remove that column from doing the weighted.mean, otherwise, both x and w will be Sepal.Length for that column

Comment: What if I need a third variable -the name again?

Comment: @Ari.stat you can use(c(where(is.numeric), -c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))`

Comment: i.e `df %>%
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)), 
        ~ weighted.mean(., w = Sepal.Length)))`

Comment: Or it can be vector of names i.e. `nm1 <- names(df)[1:2];df %>%    group_by(Species) %>%     summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -all_of(nm1)), ~ weighted.mean(., w = Sepal.Length)))`